# Batch file to search text document for a any numbers greater than 620

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Batch file to search a text file for a number greater than 620. If a number greater than 620 is found, it triggers an alert (email).

The text file looks like this: 11 files 30 files 88 files 1 files

I'm wondering if I can use a combination of if and find commands to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use somewhat like this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (test.txt) do if "%%i" gtr "620" echo %%i %%j
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(set alert=)
for /f %%i in (thetextfile.txt) do if %%i gtr 620 set alert=%%i
IF DEFINED alert ECHO sendmail found %alert% files
```